# SQL Azure automated export fails silently with new user. Permissions perhaps?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Using the Windows Azure portal I tried to complete the configuration required for the new (July 2013) automated export feature.

My default SQL Azure users password is more than 12 characters long so was rejected by the portal. I created a new user and login, set the permissions `EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'myuser';` but even though these details are accepted by the portal the automated export does not occur, failing silently.

Other users have it working with the user that was created when the database was created, but others also have my problem: they can't get it to work with a new user.

If I list the user roles via

```
SELECT
    dbU.[name] AS [user]
    , dbGp.[name] AS [Group]
FROM
    sys.database_role_members AS dbRM
    JOIN sys.database_principals AS dbU ON dbU.[principal_id] = dbRM.[member_principal_id]
    JOIN sys.database_principals AS dbGp ON dbGp.[principal_id] = dbRM.[role_principal_id]
```

all the users are db_owner - I can't see any difference between the default user and the new user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing a `CREATE DATABASE X AS COPY OF Y` operation you can only copy the database using the login that created the database on SQL Azure in the first place ([As indicated in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951631.aspx#Permissions))

I could not see a similar restriction noted for the [automated exports process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh335292.aspx#Automated_export) however this is likely the case for Import / Export operations against a database on SQL Azure.

It appears that you would have to use the original login.

Edit:  Under the **Cost Impact** section of [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql-bi-sap-cloud-crm_all_in_one_place/archive/2013/07/24/sql-azure-automated-database-export.aspx), it indicates that prior to exporting the database, a copy is created on the same server.  This means that you do indeed need to use the login that originally created the database.

Comment: I didn't know about Create Database only working for the original user. That's a bit **** as changing the original users password to be <= 12 chars will cause a service disruption on the client websites. As you indicate, it probably *does* use Create Database for the copy prior to the .bacpac export. FYI: My new user does not have access to master. I'm not even sure how to do that tbh

Comment: I expect Create Database is the reason why it fails (though I don't know how we can be sure at this point?). Thanks for your answer. I'll have to stick with my old method of creating backups for this one.

Comment: Removed the `master` question; the article highlighted in the Edit shows that you do indeed need to be logged in as the original owner.

Comment: This is definitely not ideal and I hope they grant the ability to change the database owner soon.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who hit this thread looking for why their SQL Azure automated export doesn't run, it will fail if you are trying to export federated databases.  Federated databases do not support the `CREATE DATABASE X AS COPY OF Y` construct.

Even though federations are not supported, the Azure portal will allow you to setup the automated export job for them.  However, the jobs will silently fail and the portal will give no indication as to why they didn't.

To troubleshoot your specific issue, try to run `CREATE DATABASE X AS COPY OF Y` from the master db using the credentials you specified when creating your job.  Next, see what errors you get.  This is what errors I got before I realized what was going on:

*Msg 45038, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
CREATE DATABASE AS COPY OF federation root database is not supported.*

*Msg 45038, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
CREATE DATABASE AS COPY OF federation member database is not supported.*

Answer (score 0):

If the database you are trying to Auto Export is a Free 20mb Web DB, then it will fail, as currently Azure only allows 1 free 20mb Database. So when it attempts to copy the DB, it fails as it doesn't allow you to have 2 free DBs.
So if you would like Auto export to work - you will simply need to upgrade to a paid DB.